# Was the town Jadovno near Gospić named after the concentration camp during World War 2, or was it the other way around?

Tags: world-war-two, fascism, genocide, the-balkans, croatia

What does the name "Jadovno", a town near Gospić where a concentration camp used to be during World War 2, mean? Was the town named after the concentration camp (from "jad" meaning "suffering") or was it the other way around? If it was the other way around, what does the name "Jadovno" mean then?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: Please establish that Jadovno *is* 'a town'. Viewed from above we see nothing but hills, cliffs and trees…

Comment: One translation for [jad](https://translate.google.com/?sl=hr&tl=en&text=jad&op=translate) is grief, sorrow or woe and [jadovno](https://translate.google.com/?sl=hr&tl=en&text=jadovno&op=translate) translates as miserable.

Comment: @Fred Why is that important? Clearly, "Jadovno" can be read more-or-less as "suffering", as I stated in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual pattern is that a concentration camp was built a bit 'into the woods' and then named after the nearest town, village or geographical feature. (One exception may be "[Arbeitsdorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeitsdorf_concentration_camp)", ie: 'labour village'.)

For Jadovno it is the exact same thing.

Jadovno is situated in the former županija [Lika-Krbava (County)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lika-Krbava_County). Which is and was quite thinly settled.

Serbian Wikipedia states that the camp ["was built in the *hamlet* of Jadovno."](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%88%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE)

As such it existed on [k.u.k.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_and_Royal) Hungarian maps, like [this one from 1890:](https://www.arcanum.com/hu/online-kiadvanyok/Lexikonok-a-pallas-nagy-lexikona-2/l-1005E/lika-krbava-10B42/)

[image]

zoomed:

[image]

Jadovno belongs to [Trnovac](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trnovac_(Gospi%C4%87)), and *that* unit's  population development was as follows:

| 1869 | 1931 | 1948 | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.051 | 690 | 612 | 96 |